# SSH reverse tunnel blocked second time

Tags: linux, ssh

I have an orangepi zero with an umts stick. Now I want to make a reverse tunnel to my vhost.

```
[Unit]
Description=UMTS Reverse SSH Service
ConditionPathExists=|/usr/bin
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -NTC -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i %h/.ssh/orangepi -R 7878:localhost:3000 root@xxx

# Restart every >2 seconds to avoid StartLimitInterval failure
RestartSec=3
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service is working. But if I switch off the orangepi and restart it, the tunnel does not come up because the port is still blocked by the last ssh connection on my vhost !?
Killing that pid solves the problem, but why the process is not terminated if the tunnel is gone?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your problem lies within:

> After=network.target

You should change that to:

> After=network-online.target

`network.target` doesn't mean that network is up and you're online on at least one interface. See: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

The prematurely started service is probably waiting for a timeout and blocks the connection. Verify that by starting the service manually with `systemctl start your.service` after boot and not automatically.

Comment: No, even if the network isn't up the service will try it again on failure. The problem is that the process on my vhost does not get terminated if the orangepi is gone for whatever reason. Using network-online.target is the cleaner solution but does not solve this problem.